# Send Email With only Email client application in android

Tags: android, email, android-intent

I want to implement an option to send email. Right now i can send email but problem is, Android shows many applications to send such as bluetooth, facebook, message,etc which is not required. I need to avoid this and show only email client application.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
String[] emails = {"suresh.chandani@gmail.com"}; 
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, emails); 
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri); 
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Test App"); 
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Email Body"); 
intent.setType("message/rfc822"); 
startActivity(intent);
```

If any one knows to how to achieve this please let me know

Comment: Can you show the code you are currently using?

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
String[] emails = {"suresh.chandani@gmail.com"};
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, emails);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Test App");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Email Body");
intent.setType("“message/rfc822");
startActivity(intent);

Comment: This is what i am doing now, beyerss

Answer (score 3):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse("mailto:suresh.chandani@gmail.com);    
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Test App");  
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Email Body");
startActivity(intent);
```

Credit goes to [Adams Bros Blogs](http://blog.adamsbros.org/2011/12/31/send-email-in-your-android-application/) but he does mention in his post that this only worked for gmail for him. See if you have any success with it. He does show another way of doing this that worked for him.

Answer (score 2):

To send email to a specific address, use `ACTION_SENDTO` and a `mailto:` `Uri` in your `Intent` supplied to `startActivity()`. Or, implement your own email client, using the JavaMail port for Android.