# Android intent not showing only email clients

Tags: android, email, android-intent

So I'm trying to launch a prepopulated email client with data. The content gets populated fine, however my problem is that when launching the intent, I wanted it to only show email clients to select from.
Instead, it shows Gmail, Adding to EverNote, Android Beam, Bluetooth, and some others.

I don't know if its an issue with lollipop that broke this functionality or not, as one of my managers sent me code that worked fine for him a few years ago.

My code is:

```
private void openEmailClient(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("message/rfc822");

    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{getResources().getString(R.string.contact_feedback_email_address)});
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, getResources().getString(R.string.contact_feedback_email_subject_android));

    try{
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent,intentEmailString));
    } catch(android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex){
        Log.e(EMAIL_FAIL_TAG, EMAIL_FAIL);
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Like this app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=tenmb.social.stickers  have options ??

Comment: @waheedakhtar Yeah but I only want it to show email clients, not Bluetooth and Evernote and other stuff

Comment: In feedback section of this app when you click on message image you will see less sharing options. I think these are the least things that you can get at the moment.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Send Email With only Email client application in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11672002/send-email-with-only-email-client-application-in-android)

Comment: @waheedakhtar so no way to display just mail clients?

Comment: I think so. You can reduce apps list to show but can not show a single app,.

Comment: but  if you need that code i can send you.

Comment: @waheedakhtar It's okay thanks I managed to do it a different way that works fine :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you will change your `intent.setType` like below you will get

```
intent.setType("text/plain");
```

Use

> android.content.Intent.ACTION_SENDTO

`(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);)` to get only the list of e-mail clients, with no facebook or other apps. Just the email clients.

I wouldn't suggest you get directly to the email app. Let the user choose his favorite email app. Don't constrain him.

If you use `ACTION_SENDTO`, `putExtra` does not work to add subject and text to the intent. Use Uri to add the subject and body text.

We can use `message/rfc822` instead of `"text/plain"` as the MIME type. However, that is not indicating "only offer email clients" -- it indicates "offer anything that supports `message/rfc822 data"`. That could readily include some application that are not email clients.

`message/rfc822` supports MIME Types of .mhtml, .mht, .mime

**EDIT**

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse("mailto:someone@example.com"));
 intent.putExtra("subject", "my subject");
 intent.putExtra("body", "my message");
 startActivity(intent);
```

its working ...

Comment: How can I set the subject and body using a Uri? Using ACTION_SENDTO shows things like bluetooth etc.
I want to allow the users to choose their favourite mail app but the problem is, applications like Bluetooth etc appear too.

Comment: Yep. Was going to mark my solution as the answer but I marked yours instead thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try like this it working fine for me...

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse("mailto:abc@gmail.com"));    
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Test App");  
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Email Body");
startActivity(intent);
```

Note: it only work if you have email address.

For more information please refer this link [Android - Is there a foolproof way to only show possible EMAIL clients?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8187054/android-is-there-a-foolproof-way-to-only-show-possible-email-clients)

Comment: Thanks. I ended up doing it in a similar way where it just gets the default mail client

Comment: What will happen if there is no mail app

Answer (score 0):

So I solved it. Not ideally but it works better than anything else I have tried.

I followed the google docs on doing it, which says to do this:

```
public void composeEmail(String[] addresses, String subject) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:")); // only email apps should handle this
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, addresses);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

and it now works.
This just finds a default app for handling mail. I'm not sure how it decides, but in my case it opened GMail. On a device without GMail installed, such as the Galaxy S5, it opened their mail client and prompted the user to set up email.
Doesn't give choice of app but it works